# iOS Check ViewController has ChildViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, childviewcontroller

I want to do something when viewController has any ChildViewController.

**I'm using below code to add child viewController :**

```
ParentVC *parentVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDParentVC"];

ChildVC *childVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"IDChildVC"];

[childVC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[parentVC addChildViewController:childVC];
[parentVC.view addSubview:childVC.view];
[childVC didMoveToParentViewController:parentVC];
```

Now how to check that if ParentVC has ChildVC?

Comment: `UIViewController` class has a `childViewControllers` property which you can enumerate

Answer (score 4):

You can make it like this

```
for (UIViewController *child in parentVC.childViewControllers) {
    if ([child isKindOfClass:[childVC class]) {
        //your ChildVC here
    }
}
```

Hope this help